# Symmetries of the nuclear ground state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics

Is it a reasonable assumption to consider parity and CP as symmetries of the nuclear ground state, if I want to describe a scattering process between external particles (WIMPs) and the nucleus?

I am working within the context of Direct Detection of WIMPs.